# Pylint warning W0632: How to handle with a function that can return two or three values?

Tags: python, pylint, unpack

I am using a function provided by an external library, this function can return a tuple of two or three values.

For convenience, here is a code that reproduce the issue (using the exact same return type as the problematic function):

```
from typing import Union, Optional, Tuple


def mock_framework_function(return_tree_values: bool) -> Union[Tuple[int, Optional[Union[bytes, str]]], Tuple[int, Optional[Union[bytes, str]], Optional[Union[bytes, str]]]]:
    """Represent a function that can return a tuple of two or three values"""

    if return_tree_values:
        return 0, "one", "two"

    return 1, "one"


code, value = mock_framework_function(False)  # W0632: Possible unbalanced tuple unpacking with sequence defined at line 7: left side has 2 label(s), right side has 3 value(s) (unbalanced-tuple-unpacking)
```

I use only the form that return two values, to avoid the warning, I added a _ but it makes the program crash since the function never returns three values.

How would you handle this (Except disabling the warning) ?

Comment: code, value, _ = mock_framework_function(False) get rid of the warning but will make the program crash because they are only two values to unpack, not three.

Comment: Ah, okay, yeah of course the unpacking is the issue here, which is exactly why pylint is giving the warning. The answer by Psytho is a good solution to prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

Assign them to ONE variable (which will be a tuple) and then use unpack the two values you need to two variables

```
values = mock_framework_function(False)
code, value = values[0], values[1]
```

Comment: Good solution. You might add something like `if len(values) == 2: ... else: ...` to demonstrate how to deal with this function in a more realistic scenario. This demonstrates that the assignment is always correct, but the unpacking depends on the amount of values.